# MongoDB - Mongoid map reduce basic operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have just started with MongoDB and mongoid.
The biggest problem I'm having is understanding the map/reduce functionality to be able to do some very basic grouping and such.

Lets say I have model like this:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :age, type: Integer
  field :name
  field :sdate
end
```

That model would produce objects like these:

```
#<Person _id: 9xzy0, age: 22, name: "Lucas", sdate: "2013-10-07">
#<Person _id: 9xzy2, age: 32, name: "Paul", sdate: "2013-10-07">
#<Person _id: 9xzy3, age: 23, name: "Tom", sdate: "2013-10-08">
#<Person _id: 9xzy4, age: 11, name: "Joe", sdate: "2013-10-08">
```

Could someone show how to use mongoid map reduce to get a collection of those objects grouped by the sdate field? And to get the sum of ages of those that share the same sdate field?

I'm aware of this: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce
But somehow it would help to see that applied to a real example. Where does that code go, in the model I guess, is a scope needed, etc.

I can make a simple search with mongoid, get the array and manually construct anything I need but I guess map reduce is the way here. And I imagine these js functions mentioned on the mongoid page are feeded to the DB that makes those operations internally. Coming from active record these new concepts are a bit strange.

I'm on Rails 4.0, Ruby 1.9.3, Mongoid 4.0.0, MongoDB 2.4.6 on Heroku (mongolab) though I have locally 2.0 that I should update.

Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/#MapReduce-Outputoptions

Comment: Thanks. I should have paid more attention to the mongodb docs than to mongoid. It is much better illustrated in the mongodb page you added.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Taking the examples from http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce and adapting them to your situation and adding comments to explain.

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    emit(this.sdate, { age: this.age, name : this. name }); 
      // here "this" is the record that map
      // is going to be executed on
  }  
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {   
           // this will be executed for every group that
           // has the same sdate value
    var result = { avg_of_ages: 0 };
    var sum = 0;    // sum of all ages
    var totalnum = 0  // total number of people
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      sum += value.age;    
    });
    result.avg_of_ages = sum/total   // finding the average
    return result;
  }
}

results = Person.map_reduce(map, reduce) //You can access this as an array of maps

first_average = results[0].avg_of_ages

results.each do |result|
   // do whatever you want with result
end
```

Though i would suggest you use Aggregation and not map reduce for such a simple operation. The way to do this is as follows :

```
 results = Person.collection.aggregate([{"$group" => { "_id" => {"sdate" => "$sdate"}, 
                                                "avg_of_ages"=> {"$avg" : "$age"}}}])
```

and the result will be almost identical with map reduced and you would have written a lot less code.